# Display brings up only one object of the list and list isn't adding properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list, textbox

So basically i am trying to do a project in a windows form where i determine the number of vertices and it assigns each vertex a co-ordinate and outputs it on another form. for some reason it isn't working properly could anyone take a look?

MainForm

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace assignment
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public List<Vertex> vertexList = new List<Vertex>();

        private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int vertices = 0, edges = 0;
            try
            {
                vertices = (int)Convert.ToInt32(txtVertices.Text);
                edges = (int)Convert.ToInt32(txtEdges.Text);
                if (vertices < 0)
                    MessageBox.Show("Vertices cannot be less than 0", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                else
                    if (edges < 0 || edges > 1)
                        MessageBox.Show("Edges have to be 0..1", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    else
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("Graph successfully created", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                        for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++)
                        {
                            Vertex vertex = new Vertex();
                            Vertex vertex1 = vertex.CreateVertex(vertices);
                            vertexList.Add(vertex1);                             
                        }

                        VertexDisplay display = new VertexDisplay();
                        display.DisplayVertices(vertexList);
                        display.Show();
                    }

            }
            catch(Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Vertices  or edges Cannot be left out", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Vertex Class

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace assignment
{
    public class Vertex
    {
        public int x;        
        public int y;
        public int z;
        public int vertexID;

        public int X
        {
            get { return x; }
            set { x = value; }
        }        

        public int Y
        {
            get { return y; }
            set { y = value; }
        }        

        public int Z
        {
            get { return z; }
            set { z = value; }
        }        

        public int VertexID
        {
            get { return vertexID; }
            set { vertexID = value; }
        }

        public Vertex CreateVertex(int noOfVertex)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            Vertex vertex = new Vertex(x, y, z, vertexID);
            MainForm mainform = new MainForm();
            vertex.x = rnd.Next(0, 100);
            vertex.y = rnd.Next(0, 100);
            vertex.z = rnd.Next(0, 100);

            vertex.vertexID = rnd.Next(0, noOfVertex);

            return(vertex);
        }
        public Vertex()
        {

        }
        public Vertex(int x, int y, int z, int id)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
            this.vertexID = id;
        }
    }

}
```

Display From

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace assignment
{
    public partial class VertexDisplay : Form
    {
        public VertexDisplay()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainForm mainform = new MainForm();
            DisplayVertices(mainform.vertexList);
        }
        public void DisplayVertices(List<Vertex>vertexList)
        {
            int x, y, z, id;
            foreach(Vertex vertexDetails in vertexList)
            {
                x = vertexDetails.X;
                y = vertexDetails.Y;
                z = vertexDetails.Z;
                id = vertexDetails.VertexID;

                txtVertexDisplay.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, " ID: " + id + " x: " + x + " y: " + y + " z: " + z);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain exactly what isn't working?

Comment: the co-ordinates of the vertices are not showing up as supposed to when i try to display them only one is showing instead of how many there are in the list

Comment: so in main form you are creating vertex display, and in vertex display you are creating main form, and you wonder why you have only one element on list?

Comment: txtVertexDisplay.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, " ID: " + id + " x: " + x + " y: " + y + " z: " + z);  <- U mean this ? You are setting Text property each iteration so after foreach loop it will show You only last item

Comment: Can you please tell me which one to eliminate i am new to this :(

Comment: I'm glad it works :) Accept answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting txtVertexDisplay.Text property inside a Foreach loop so You are setting this each time loop iterate. Its not concatenation it's always beeing set to be exactly something. If You want to concatenate Your output - use some temporary string property and += operator. See below:

```
 public void DisplayVertices(List<Vertex>vertexList)
    {
        String displayText = string.Empty;
        int x, y, z, id;
        foreach(Vertex vertexDetails in vertexList)
        {
            x = vertexDetails.X;
            y = vertexDetails.Y;
            z = vertexDetails.Z;
            id = vertexDetails.VertexID;

            displayText += string.Join(Environment.NewLine, " ID: " + id + " x: " + x + " y: " + y + " z: " + z);
        }
        txtVertexDisplay.Text = displayText;
    }
```

Comment: Generally speaking it's better to use a `StringBuilder` than string concatenation when building up a string in a loop.

Comment: Well usually i would agree with You since that's what StringBuilder was invented to, but in some tiny examples like this it's not a sin to use concatenation :)